# ¿Cómo mostrar el valor seleccionado (SELECTED) de COmuna en CodeIgniter 3.x?

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter

Cómo echo un valor de la consulta de selección en codeigniter?

**View**

```
<label for="region" class="col-3 col-form-label">Region <span> * </span></label>                                

  <div class="col-3">

    <select class="form-control" name="regionI" id="regionI">
        <option value="">- Seleccione -</option>                                        
        <?php foreach($result_region as $region) : $selected = FALSE;

            if ($region->id_region == $interprete[0]['regionI_id']){
             $selected = TRUE;
            }
        ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $region->id_region;?>" <?php echo set_select('regionI', $region->id_region, $selected); ?>><?php echo $region->nombre_region;?></option>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </select>
    <?php echo form_error('regionI', '<div class="form-control-label">', '</div>'); ?>

  </div>

<label for="comuna" class="col-3 col-form-label">Comuna <span> * </span></label>

 <div class="col-3">

    <select class="form-control" name="comunaI" id="comunaI"></select>
        <?php echo form_error('comunaI', '<div class="form-control-label">', '</div>'); ?>  

    </div>
```

**Controller**

```
public function comunasI() {

 $id = $this->input->post('id');

 $query['interprete'] = $this->regiones_model->getComunas($id);

 $output = null;

 foreach($query['interprete'] as $comuna) :
  //$selected = FALSE;

    if ($comuna->id_comuna == $interprete[0]['comunaI_id']) {
     //SELECTED = TRUE                
     $output .= "<option value='".$comuna->id_comuna."' selected='TRUE'); >".$comuna->nombre_comuna."</option>";

    }
    else
    {
     $output .= "<option value='".$comuna->id_comuna."'); >".$comuna->nombre_comuna."</option>";
    }

    endforeach;

    echo $output; 

   }
}
```

**Ajax desplegableno Region y Comuna**

```
$(document).ready(function() {  

 $("#regionI").change(function(){  

   var url = '<?php echo base_url()?>index.php/'; 
   var id = $('#regionI').val();

   $.ajax({  

    url: url+"interprete/perfil/comunasI",  
    data: { id : id },  
    type: "POST",  
    success:function(data){                
     $("#comunaI").html(data);  
    }  

  });  

 });

});
```

Result:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [regionI_id] => 8 [comunaI_id] => 146 ))
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comuna no recibe valor.

Comment: se mas preciso en tu pregunta

Comment: @Sergio1871 ???